# Error when changing leader to space

Tags: vim, latex

My document will compile when the leader key is left as "\" but if I change it to "\< Space >" (ignore the space on either side of "Space") or " " , my document won't compile. Here's how I've set it along with how I'm compiling it (.vimrc).

```
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
nnoremap <leader>ll :w<CR>:!latexmk -pdf %<CR>
```

It works on my ubuntu 14.04 partition and mac but not my Arch linux partition.

Comment: You can write `"\<Space>"` by wrapping it in ` characters.

Answer (score 0):

It can help if you try replace `let mapleader = "\<Space>"` by

```
let mapleader=" "
```

or try this workaround

```
map <SPACE> <leader>
```

instead if nothing helps.